# Why is my app bar being overlapped by the items in the screen when scrolling?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

Like I described in the question, when I run the app and scroll down the content simply goes over the top bar until the lower margin of the phone's notification panel . I also cant click on the 3-lines icon on the left to open the side navigation drawer. Rather I have to drag it from the left to open it.It's like my top bar is not even noticed. I am working on the app in android studio.

The following is my code for the XML page containing it:

Activity front page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_front_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#3B1187"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="107dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_box"
                    android:layout_width="260dp"
                    android:layout_height="84dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="cursive"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:onClick="onClickNews"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="35dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/news_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="277dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#3B1187"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fact"
                    android:layout_width="259dp"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="cursive"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:onClick="onClickFacts"
                    android:text="Facts"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="35dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/real_facts_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="286dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#3B1187"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="89dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/steps" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/step"
                    android:layout_width="274dp"
                    android:layout_height="77dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="cursive"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:onClick="onClickSteps"
                    android:text="Steps"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="35dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        //newsletteretc
        <GridLayout
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/newsletter"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Newsletter"
                        android:id="@+id/newtext"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ad"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingRight="100dp">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
        //share
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#00FFB7">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnCount="3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:rowCount="1"
                    android:textAlignment="center">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/facebook"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fb_new" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/facebook"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/insta_new" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageButton2"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_front_page"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_front_page_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Another XML file especially for the app bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Front_page">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_front_page" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note : when creating new activity I chose 'Navigation Drawer' activity and found there to be an XML particularly for top app/tool bar.

Before scrolling : 
[image before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJUYt.png)

After scrolling:
[Image after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j95Xn.png)

I would like for the items to scroll under the top bar.

**Edit** : Given below is the changed part of the code that is also causing the content to be displayed overlapping the app bar at the start of the page itself and continues to overlap during the scrolling:

```
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_front_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior ="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: please attach a screenshot of your problem and desired design?

Comment: @GaneshChandra, `views` in your layout file are overly crowded. Try moving some of the views to another `Activity` or `Fragment` depending upon the app design. On top of that, you want to show a `ViewPager` (`height` and `width` set to `match_parent`) below the `appbar` ?. Your both `ViewPager` and `AppBar` is supposed the fit the page as that is how you supplied their `layout_height/width` attribute. Another thing that is wrong here is `android:layout_below="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`. You are supposed to provide view `id` of that view you want current view to be below of.

Comment: @Quicklearner i have attached the screenshots, you can take a look.

Comment: @cgb_pandey could you elaborate what you meant regarding the viewpager?

Comment: @GaneshChandra try adding `app:layout_behaviour="...AppBarScrolling"` in that view which you want to be below `AppBar`.

Comment: @GaneshChandra I meant that `AppBar` should be above the `ViewPager`. The recommended format is `CoordinatorLayout` > `AppBarLayout` > `ToolBar`(inside `AppBarLayout`) > (Then ViewPager or some other content view) in a top-down manner

Comment: @cgb_pandey I tried adding the respective `app: layout_behaviour=".."` in the scroll view but I didnt find any change upon running the app. Moreover , after messing around with my code , the content is now displayed overlapping the topbar before scrolling itself. For a clearer idea I suggest you refer to the second image url that I uploaded in my question description.

Comment: I think I find out what is wrong here. Try moving the code for `NestedScrollView` along with all of its children to `content_front_page.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as pointed out by @cgb_pandey is to simply move the code of the scrollview as well as it's children to the `content_front_page.xml`.